# c++ : unordered map with pair of string_viewes

Tags: c++11, string-view

Here is a code snippet I have :

```
    struct PairHasher {
        size_t operator()(const std::pair<std::string_view, std::string_view>& stop_stop) const {
            return hasher(stop_stop.first) + 37*hasher(stop_stop.second);
        }
        std::hash<std::string_view> hasher;
    };


BOOST_FIXTURE_TEST_CASE(unordered_map_string_view_pair_must_be_ok, TestCaseStartStopMessager)
{
    const std::vector<std::string> from_stops = {"from_0", "from_1", "from_2"};
    const std::vector<std::string> to_stops = {"to_0", "to_1", "to_2"};

    std::unordered_map<std::pair<std::string_view, std::string_view>, std::int32_t, TransportCatalogue::PairHasher> distance_between_stops;
    for ( std::size_t idx = 0; idx < from_stops.size(); ++idx) {
        std::cout << from_stops[idx] << " : " << to_stops[idx] << std::endl;
        distance_between_stops[std::pair(from_stops[idx], to_stops[idx])] = idx;
    }

    std::cout << "MAP CONTENT :" << std::endl;
    for (auto const& x : distance_between_stops)
    {
        std::cout << x.first.first << " : " << x.first.second << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I expect to see 3 pairs inside the container, but there is only 1 concerning to the output :

```
MAP CONTENT :
from_2 : to_2
```

So, where are two more pair lost? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving my comment to an answer.

This is pretty sneaky.  I noticed in [Compiler Explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/fzPWzx5P1) that changing:

```
distance_between_stops[std::pair(from_stops[idx], to_stops[idx])] = idx;
```

to

```
distance_between_stops[std::pair(std::string_view{from_stops[idx]}, std::string_view{to_stops[idx]})] = idx;
```

fixes the bug.  This hints that the problem lies in some implicit `string` -> `string_view` conversion.  And indeed that is the case, but it is hidden behind one extra layer.

`std::pair(from_stops[idx], to_stops[idx])` creates a `std::pair<std::string, std::string>`, but `distance_between_stops` requires a `std::pair<std::string_view, std::string_view>`.  When we insert values into the map, this conversion happens implicitly via overload #5 [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair):

```
template <class U1, class U2>
constexpr pair(pair<U1, U2>&& p);
```

> 5. Initializes `first` with `std::forward<U1>(p.first)` and second with `std::forward<U2>(p.second)`.
>
> - This constructor participates in overload resolution if and only if `std::is_constructible_v<first_type, U1&&>` and `std::is_constructible_v<second_type, U2&&>` are both `true`.
> - This constructor is `explicit` if and only if `std::is_convertible_v<U1&&, first_type>` is `false` or `std::is_convertible_v<U2&&, second_type>` is `false`.

(For reference, `std::is_constructible_v<std::string_view, std::string&&>` and `std::is_convertible_v<std::string&&, std::string_view>` are both `true`, so we know this overload is viable and implicit.)

See the problem yet?  When we use the map's `operator[]`, it has to do an implicit conversion to create a key with the proper type.  This implicit conversion constructs a pair of `string_view`s that are viewing the **temporary** memory from the local pair of `string`s, not the underlying strings in the `vector`.  In other words, it is conceptually similar to:

```
std::string_view foo(const std::string& s) {
    std::string temp = s + " foo";
    return temp;
}
int main() {
    std::string_view sv = foo("hello");
    std::cout << sv << "\n";
}
```

Clang emits a warning for this small example, but not OP's full example, which is unfortunate:

```
warning: address of stack memory associated with local variable 'temp' returned [-Wreturn-stack-address]
    return temp;
           ^~~~
```